# Нутро как аналог шестого чувства

Tags: синонимы

Мы с мамой частенько разгадываем кроссворды в газетах и журналах. И вот так очень часто встречается вопрос: "Интуиция, шестое чувство". И ответ неизменный: "Нутро". Видимо, авторы вопроса исходят из поговорки "нутром чую". Мне это ужасно режет слух.
Но вопрос встречается толь часто, что я уже начинаю сомневаться: может слово "нутро" имеет и такое значение?
А что скажут специалисты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понял вопрос... О каком значении речь?
***Нутро - интуиция?*** Да, в ироническом употреблении имеется именно это значение.  
***Нутро - шестое чувство?*** Нет. Так тоже может кто-то представить, но это неправильно. Интуиция к чувствам не относится. Т.е. при таком употреблении тут надо говорить уже не о значении слова "нутро" или "интуиция", а о неправильном употреблении понятия "шестое чувство". Ну или тоже об иронии, но избитой - хотя от того не менее неудачной.

А что касается кроссвордов, то я давно даже не видел, как их разгадывают, эта забава, мне кажется, потихоньку теряет былую популярность. Но при этом еще помню времена, когда было очень модно в "легенде" (формулировках определений) кроссвордов использовать подобные полушутливые значения. Дело в общем-то вкуса, кому-то нравилось, иногда подобные шутки могли быть довольно тонкими. Но в данном конкретном случае, как сказал, ирония не совсем удачная.

Comment: Ой, не знаю. Те шутки, что попадались в кроссвордах мне, были на уровне "Аншлага")))  
Кстати, у нас в городе я очень часто вижу разгадывающих кроссворды людей. Какая-никакая, а тренировка мозгов.